# Python - Must add r when opening a file

Tags: python, file, text

I have several .py files and I can open my file everywhere, except in my test.py file (I test scripts and functions there) instead of this:

```
file = open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\key_values.txt", "r")
```

I need to use this (with r) to avoid error:

```
file = open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\key_values.txt", "r")
```

I get this error: (when I try to open a file without r in my test.py script)

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: You are running `test.py` with Python3, and the other files with Python2.

Comment: Nope, I knw whats the problem, see my comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Backslash is an escape character](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), so you can include characters like `"\n"` (new line) and `"\t"` (tab). The `r` before the string means means "my backslashes are not escape characters".

Interestingly, it looks like your string `"C:\Users\User\Desktop\key_values.txt"` works ok in python 2 because none of the backslashes are part of anything looking like a known escape sequence. But in python 3, `"\Uxxxx"` indicates a unicode character. So maybe that is why some of your python files can cope and some can't.

Comment: But i can open my file in other .py project without raw

Comment: I will mark this as answer, but i need to wait 3 minutes. (Probably anti-spam)

Comment: It works ok in other file because there it's like this: file = open(user_input, "r") user_input is file path that user enters.. It isn't defined in a script itself

Comment: *always* use raw string or always escape \, unfortunately Python is broken in that it allows unknown escape sequences in strings to go without warnings.

Comment: That means i shoud use r every time i need to open something that contains backslashes, like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbqzzbl7hu4drcp/key_values.txt?dl=0 Right ?

Comment: If you are putting a **string literal** in your code, you should escape backslashes or use an `r` prefix. It doesn't apply to text read in from a file.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are OK.. but this a time saving trick:

Try using slashes instead of backslashes:

```
file = open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/key_values.txt", "r")
```

It works in Windows. Tried with Python 2.7

Hope this helps